# Синоним к "слитно": "одним словом" или "в одно слово"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синонимы

Как правильно сказать: "пишется одним словом" или "пишется в одно слово"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 4):

В значении "слитно" правилен вариант "**в одно слово**". Возможны и менее формальные выражения ("*как одно слово*" и т. п.), однако за устойчивым словосочетанием "**одним словом(, ...)**" закрепился другой смысл: это о замене *нескольких* слов одним (новым). Таким риторическим приёмом подводят итог ранее сказанному, фокусируя внимание собеседника (или читателя) на точно подобранном слове. Поэтому вариант "одним словом" неудачен.

Answer (score 1):

Уау, только не "одним словом"! *В одно*.

(Хотя *слитно* филологически на месте. Но, например, первоклашке можно продублировать: *врасплох* пишется в одно слово, слитно.

Это чтоб потихоньку к терминам привыкал.)